# Mysql while with variable dynamic

Tags: mysql, variables, dynamic, while-loop

I need to dynamically retrieve the variable in my while, but do not know if I'm using the correct way, in the code below I need to retrieve the table name to make the inclusion, but returns an error. This test is only an example, actually I will use this procedure to create a Trigger for the tables.
Ex:

```
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tb_name VARCHAR(8000);

SET @db_name = "test_ph";

SET @qtd_tables = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = @db_name);

WHILE i < @qtd_tables DO

    SET tb_name = (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = @db_name LIMIT i,1);

    INSERT INTO tb_name(name, email) VALUES('test', 'test@test.com');

    SET i = i + 1;

END WHILE;
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable 'tb_name'

Comment: the variable attributed this line:
SET tb_name = (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = @db_name LIMIT i,1);
is not found